# Why is there so little interest in the election?

Tags: discussion, election

While there is still some time left, I'd like to get some insight into the community why there is so little interest in becoming a moderator.

I have seen plenty of active users that could run for election, because they are currently already doing most of the work. I guess there are reasons and I'd like any whiff of information I can get about it.

I hope some of the regulars might reconsider and I hope to have you in the candidate pool.

Comment: I don't know if you noticed, but there were two more new nominations just before you posted this ;)

Comment: Damn, I was hoping for a shoo-in :)

Comment: @ToddMinehardt, the election wouldn't have taken place, I asked a CM and they needed a competitive election for a full site or it wouldn't take place.. I was hoping for the same as well as it was the only way I could win :P

Comment: I believe that the responsibility which comes with being a moderator is what is keeping people away from the election. While in theory it sounds fun to be a moderator but the responsibility turns off many people. They don't want to become moderators and than feel bad when they are not able to help the community when they are stuck in other worldly affairs.

Comment: @SafdarFaisal That would explain the postponing of the election because in beta sites (e.g. Astronomy.SE), the election didn't took place and went ahead with 1 candidate who nominated for 1 position of mod team.

Comment: Just as a small data point, but which may represent other people's cases: my participation in the site has become much smaller over the past few years as career progression demands an ever increasing investment of time and effort. I could not do Chem.SE justice if I were to volunteer as a moderator. Who knows when or if that will change...

Comment: @NilayGhosh You have 18k rep on Chem.SE and see to be quite aware of what's going on in the broader Stack Exchange network. Why don't you run for the election? You have about as much rep as the top 2 current candidates combined!!!

Comment: @user1271772 Thanks! But I prefer not to run for the election because of my work schedule. I became quite busy and so I am not that active as I was used to in the past 3-4 years. I occasionally login and browse some question (search for duplicates/related question and link them in comments) and if I have free time, I answer 1-2 questions. I am not that active in chats or review queues or other mod activities. I feel like I will not do justice to this community if I volunteer as a mod. I also feel that the nominated candidates will do a great job if elected as mods. Cheers!

Comment: The existing candidates display enough variation in background and viewpoints. I don't feel it is therefore important to compete for a position that someone else might enjoy more and be better at!

Comment: In addition I have mixed feelings about where the site should be headed. Since I started participating I've become aware of issues with the focus of the site, as noted in a question by orthocresol. I put quite a bit of thought into that question but could not come up with a satisfactory answer. There is a flood of questions that should not be up (they are duplicates mostly), but a ready solution does not come to mind. I think I can do more or as much by answering, closing, voting, commenting, visiting queues, without having to commit to a particular amount of effort or responsibility.

Comment: I don't want to commit if I am not dead sure I can put in the time (I do thank the mods for having addressed some of this question by estimating their own time commitments).

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I am happy to see you all care and I can understand all of your reasons. When I started to conceive this post, shortly after the initial nomination phase run out, there were not enough candidates to actually run the election. I am happy this turned around, and I feel like this post has served its purpose. Thanks again y'all.

Comment: @BuckThorn From my personal experience, you don't need to have a good answer to that to be a moderator ;-) Anyway, it's good to have you around, mod or no mod. Same to others in this comment thread.

Comment: @orthocresol Thanks for your comment. I went and threw my hat in the ring despite my own comment. Alea iacta est.

Answer (score 11):

> [OP] I'd like to get some insight into the community why there is so little interest in becoming a moderator.

My work and life schedule sometimes allows me to invest a lot of time into this site, doing a deep dive into a question, and sometimes I don't have any time at all. So while the total time spent on the site might already be similar to that of a moderator, it is not spread out over the week, month or year for me.

> [OP] I have seen plenty of active users that could run for election, because they are currently already doing most of the work.

The work I do is very unbalanced, with most time spent on comments and answering questions, too little time spent on voting and much too little time spent on closing questions. I do occasionally post on meta, mostly to complain about this or that question being closed.

> [OP] I hope some of the regulars might reconsider and I hope to have you in the candidate pool.

I share that hope. I would encourage folks who are retired, who have a steady job but miss naive questions from science learners, who are launching into a teaching career and have good time-management so that they don't get sucked in by ChemistrySE so much they can't do their real job, to self-nominate.